# Pull outside variable inside Fb.api callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, scope

I'm having trouble understanding how I can bring a variable that is set outside a Fb.api call, inside that call's callback function. The variable `photoid`is set inside a `for` loop, and then inside that `for` loop, I use that changing `photoid` to make a FB.api calls. (I even use `photoid` to construct the calls, you'll see).  That part all works great, but what I notice in my console is that `photoid` is not passed into that callback function, such that I'm trying to save all the photoid's which match a previously set variable (`taggedpersonid = specialfriendvar`).

I believe the solution has something to do with closures (maybe), but I don't understand them very well, and was hoping for some help. How can I get each `photoid` variable inside my callback function, such that it will successfully get saved into my `photosbasket` array, if the match is true?

```js
function proceedToResult() {
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    var fbid = response.id;
    var profile_name_beta = response.name;
    console.log(profile_name_beta);
    FB.api('/me/photos', {
        fields: ['id'],
        limit: 200
      },
      function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response && !response.error) {
          if (response.data.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
              var photoid = response.data[i].id;
              console.log(photoid);
              FB.api('' + photoid + '/tags', function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log("inside photoid is" + photoid);
                for (var l = 0; l < response.data.length; l++) {
                  var taggedpersonid = response.data[l].id;
                  if (taggedpersonid == specialfriendvar) { // if photo has tagged same as chosen friend
                    photosbasket.push(photoid);
                    console.log(photosbasket);
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );

  });
}
```

Comment: You could simple make your request to `/photo-id?fields=id,tags` instead – then the API would return the id as well, and you can access it as part of the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another function, which would scope the variable to that function and make your code a little more readable:

```
function proceedToResult() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        var fbid = response.id;
        var profile_name_beta = response.name;
        console.log(profile_name_beta);
        FB.api('/me/photos', {
                fields: ['id'],
                limit: 200
            },
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    if (response.data.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                            var photoid = response.data[i].id;
                            console.log(photoid);
                            getPhoto(photoid);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );

    });
}

function getPhoto(photoid) {
    FB.api('' + photoid + '/tags', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log("inside photoid is" + photoid);
        for (var l = 0; l < response.data.length; l++) {
            var taggedpersonid = response.data[l].id;
            if (taggedpersonid == specialfriendvar) { // if photo has tagged same as chosen friend
                photosbasket.push(photoid);
                console.log(photosbasket);
            }
        }
    });
}
```